# Eclipse EGit | Branch Diff

Tags: eclipse, git-branch, egit, pull-request

Currently using Eclipse Mars.1 and installed EGit from *Eclipse MarketPlace*.

Does Eclipse EGit has a similar feature of SourceTree wherein you could pick N or all commits inside a branch and compare it (`git diff`) to which branch is was checked-out from?

I was trying to follow low-level git branching standards relying only on Eclipse EGit tools (without terminal, SourceTree, Pull Request functionality, et.al.). But I'm only limited to seeing commit-diffs and not a branch-commit-diff view.

Comment: I have tried to provide an answer, but although I know egit, I don't know SourceTree, so perhaps SourceTree has some specific feature egit does not have or egit implements differently. Do you have a screenshot or more explicit items in a git history you are trying to compare but can't manage at the moment?

Answer (score 13):

I think you can compare anything to anything in egit.

e.g.:

- You can click on any two commits in the History view and, from context menu, choose *Compare With Each Other*
- You can select two branches in the *Git Repositories* view and, from context menu, choose *Synchonize with each other*
- You can right click on any branch in the *Git Repositories* view and choose *Synchonize with workspace*

And the list goes on ad infinitum (practically).

Comment: Problem is. I did this in project explorer. so I was AHA! git repository view. But both lead to the synchronize nonsens, and then Im in a new synchronization "view" or whatever... and then what? -_-. Jeezus christ eclipse makes everything overcomplicated.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that in the Eclipse world "Synchronize" means "Compare". To me "Synchronize" implies that two things will become aligned, or anyway something will get changed, and that's why I never used it before to compare two branches.